# Tinkers Construct Mod Not Making Casts in Smeltery

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tinkers-construct

I am playing on Tinkers Construct in mincraft 1.5.2 because some of my other mods are not supported past that. I have correctly set up the smeltery and am trying to make part cast so I can make tools out of the metals, but when I set a part on the casting table and right click on the seared faucet no Aluminum-Bronze comes out to make the cast. By the way I have also tried to use gold instead and it did not work.

Comment: Are you using the right metal (AKA. Gold) to make your cast?

Comment: it's aluminum **brass** to make the casts

Comment: Both Gold and Aluminum Brass can be used to make casts.  Aluminum Brass has very, very few applications other than casts so it should be used over Gold (if you're sane).

Comment: @SentinelGaming How did you fix it? Can you make & accept an answer, or, if one on the commenters gave your answer, ask them to make an answer & accept it?